# error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted

Tags: git, github

```
Enumerating objects: 18, done.
Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size        
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly2.20 MiB/s
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 2.25 GiB | 6.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Your question was really just one big code block (so I formatted it as one). In general, while including the errors like this *is* a good idea, you should *also* add some framing text explaining why you ran the commands you ran (and showing those commands) and what you expected. See also [ask].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GitHub has a limit on the maximum size of a pack that's transmitted during a push to prevent denial of service attacks.  That limit is 2 GB, and you're trying to push more data than that.

You should try to push data more incrementally.  For example, if you were trying to push twelve commits with `git push origin main`, you could try to push a few at a time by doing `git push origin main^8:main`, then `git push origin main^4:main`, and then `git push origin main`.  That will push the first four commits, then the next four, and then the final four.

If you have one giant commit you're trying to push, you'll need to split it up into smaller commits and then push those incrementally.

Comment: I added about 1MB of bmp files, and updated the repo's gitconfig, and now get this message.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I ran this command:

```js
git config --global core.compression 0
```

then pushed again and it worked

Comment: Do you know what that does?

Comment: worked for me as well

Comment: The git config `--global core.compression 0` command sets the compression level for Git objects to 0, effectively turning off compression. This means that Git will not compress the data when storing it in its repository.

In a Git repository, objects (such as blobs, trees, and commits) are stored in a compressed format by default to save space. By setting core.compression to 0, you are instructing Git not to compress these objects, which might result in larger repository size but could be useful in scenarios where you want to minimize CPU usage and prioritize disk space.

Answer (score -1):

Below git command worked for me

**git push -f origin <branch_name>**

```
         OR
```

**git push --force origin <branch_name>**

Example:  git push -f origin develop