# Got the `Error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted`

Tags: python, git, google-colaboratory, push

I faced a very simiilar problem as in [error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69427700/error-rpc-failed-curl-55-send-failure-connection-was-aborted).

However, when I do

```
!git push origin main^10:main
```

in *google colab* I got the error `error: src refspec main^10 does not match any.`

How can i solve this problem?

Problem:

```
Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.     
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69427700/error-rpc-failed-curl-55-send-failure-connection-was-aborted)

Comment: @Eng_Farghly Hi, I followed the solution in that post but unfortunately didn't work..

Comment: You have two completely different errors: one is that `main^10` is meaningless and hence is failing (did you mean `main~10`?). The other is this RPC failure, which is generally a network issue.